# Can I use anything for android package name?

Tags: android

I used my android package name as **lostaliens.crocusgames.lostaliens** as opposed to the conventional method of starting with com in the form of **com.xxxx.xxxx**

Now it has passed 36 hours since I published my app and I still cannot find my app in Google Play nor at the direct link that includes the package name.

Can it be because of my unusual package name? Or does it have nothing to do with it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all search before ask.. Second.. I had same issue once.. It will take time then it will reflect on Play Store.. Don't worry.. just keep checking..

Answer (score 1):

No, Package name is not an issue for your Application is not published.

The package name is used for unique identification for your application. In android uses the package name to determine one application has been installed or not. The general naming is: com.companyname.applicationname eg: com.android.Camera COM is refers to commercial application (just like .com, most people register their app as a com app)

Answer (score 0):

Nop, package name is not an issue at all, you can give any name to your application's package. Because the main intention of package name is to uniquely identify the app. So you can give any name as a your package name. com.XXX.XXXX is the professional way to give the name of package, 90% of the developers are using this format. So package name is not an issue, just check your google play account and check, is your app is properly submitted to play store or not.